# What is ZSH's "compadd' equivalent in linux bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, zsh

What is ZSH's "compadd' equivalent in linux bash? What should I use instead?
Thanks

Comment: As opposed to FreeBSD's bash?

Comment: Thanks for question, sorry if I'm unclear, totally new in ZSH. I found something which I'd like to use in my .bashrc file. The original ZSH commands have a "compadd" in it but when I use it in bashrc the terminal yields unknown command. Is there anything instead of compadd which is used by bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing no, there's not a direct equivalent. ZSH is more extensible and has a much greater focus on searching and completion than Bash.

`compadd` is a zsh `completion builtin`, documented in `man zshcompwid`. As far as I'm aware, bash does not have an equivalent of a completion widget, although you may perhaps be able to extend the functionality of bash yourself.

A link to the `compadd` documentation is [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshcompwid).

A quick search leads me to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html) describing the bash completion builtins, neither of which appear to have comparable functionality to `compadd`. If you're interested in discovering how bash uses completion, [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html#Programmable-Completion) is probably worth a read.

My personal suggestion, though, is to shift to ZSH over Bash, if you're interested at all in customising your shell. If you don't customise, there's little difference, but if you do, ZSH has far, far more knobs and dials for your tuning pleasure, and by default has some nifty features I would really miss in Bash (history shared between sessions comes to mind, for example).

A word of warning: be prepared for complexity. The [ZSH manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/zsh_a4.pdf) is a good read, too.

Comment: many thanks for great explonation, hadn't had an idea where to start and now I gotit! Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What does `compadd` do? I can only guess from Googling, but it seems it is connected to completion. So Google for `bash completion`.